# Django 1.8.10 - test framework not finding my static files

Tags: python, django

This is a django project that we use to have test framework working locally running unit and functional tests. We then didnt look at for ~2 months and something has changed and I am not sure what yet.

Running the command:

```
python manage.py test test_deploy.functional_tests --settings=app.settings.local
```

I am getting the error:

```
Not Found: /static/assets/css/styles.400383614f0b.css
Not Found: /static/assets/js/mqtt-global.fb8230b7da31.js
Not Found: /static/assets/js/jquery-validate-min.7b9b8777185d.js
Not Found: /static/assets/js/registration/login.c8a1a15757a7.js
Not Found: /static/assets/css/styles.400383614f0b.css
Not Found: /static/assets/images/favicon-32.21410c731917.png
Not Found: /static/assets/images/favicon-192.86084ccb3d72.png
Not Found: /static/assets/images/xxx-logo.3e8cbbad4c76.svg
Not Found: /static/assets/js/xxxx-global.fb8230b7da31.js
Not Found: /static/assets/js/jquery-validate-min.7b9b8777185d.js
Not Found: /static/assets/js/registration/login.c8a1a15757a7.js
Not Found: /static/assets/css/styles.400383614f0b.css
```

For the functional tests, a browser opens but none of the assets are loaded, because it can't find them:

local settings file:

```
from .base import *
import os

from os.path import join, abspath, dirname

DEBUG = True

DEBUG_TOOLBAR_PATCH_SETTINGS = False


TEST_APPS = (
    'debug_toolbar',
)
INSTALLED_APPS += TEST_APPS
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

ADMINS = (
    ('xxx', 'xxx@xxx.xx'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

DEFAULT_HOST='xx'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
       'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
       'NAME': 'xx',
       'USER': 'xx',
       'PASSWORD': '',
       'HOST': 'localhost',
       'PORT': '5432',
   }
}

EMAIL_HOST = 'localhost'
EMAIL_PORT = 1025
EMAIL_HOST_USER = ''
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = ''
EMAIL_USE_TLS = False

TESTFILES_FOLDER = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../test_deploy/functional_tests')

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.filebased.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_FILE_PATH = BASE_DIR # change this to a proper location

STATIC_ROOT = "xx"

# You might want to use sqlite3 for testing in local as it's much faster.
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'testing@example.com'

STATIC_ROOT = join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static/')
STATICFILES_DIRS = ()
```

Comment: STATICFILES_DIRS needs to include your staticfiles directories I guess

Comment: Can you put the folders containing your static files in `STATICFILES_DIRS = ()`?

Comment: Then run `collectstatic`.